# Add a temporary tag-request feature?

Tags: feature-request, tags

As a new user to a specific community, I was asking a question. However, I was not able to add the specific topic tags I wanted to as they did not exist yet, and being a new member of that community I didn't have anywhere near the rep needed to create a tag.

Would it be an idea to allow new members of a community to "request" a tag to be temporarily created for them if no other similar tag exists, then that moderators check to see if these tags are relevant or not, and then approve or disapprove the temporarily created tags?

For this idea it may also be necessary to create a tag "blacklist" that irrelevant tags to certain communities can be added to, so that if someone would try to create this they would automatically be denied.

Comment: As a note, many sites already have tag blacklists...

Comment: The number one reason you can't find a tag for the thing you're asking about is that it's offtopic. The number two reason is that tags on that site aren't organized the way you think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with this is that one of two things must happen:

- either the question will have no tag for a while, until the request is approved
- or the question may have a structurally-wrong tag (singular vs plural, dashes vs underscores, spelling mistake, etc) for a while until someone fixes it

Neither of these is good. If you rebut "oh, it wouldn't have **no** tag, I would put some on it that were close to appropriate" well you can do that without this technique, and include a request for the tag in the body of the question or as a comment. People do this all the time today.

Many sites have idiomatic tag-naming schemes that take time to learn. For example [Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/tags) uses multiple synonyms in a single tag name, for example [<kbd>stools-fecal-matter-poop</kbd>](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stools-fecal-matter-poop). [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags) avoids words that are airport codes, so they have [<kbd>sea-travel</kbd>](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-travel) rather than [<kbd>sea</kbd>](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea). On [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags), should you be creating a tag for the author, the book, or the series? And so on. By the time you know the site well enough to work out exactly what the tag should be, you probably have the rep to do it. And even if you won't, that's an argument for lowering the rep required, not for allowing "let's try this anyway even though I don't know how it works" suggested tags.

Comment: Thank you, I stand corrected in my ways of thinking and now have a better knowledge of how this works :D

Answer (score 6):

I don't really think it is necessary to automatize this.

Usually you can just comment, or add it as short request under your question body. Editors who think it is necessary will then either create the tag, or remove the request from the body and explain what is wrong with the tag.

Another option is to ask on the per-site meta, but that requires at least some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice here, to me seems to be

- Put the best existing tags that fit you can find first
- Put in a request on meta, or in a comment if meta is inaccessible, that "these tags would be appropriate but don't exist". If its on meta, you could also add an example tag wiki and excerpt to show you *really get it* (also tags empty of these make me sad. If you make a tag, make a start on it).

Comment: The issue with this however, would be that new users might find this a hassle, or this would need explaining. I am relatively new myself, and I had no idea about how this worked. Also, if the question would already have been answered, I wouldn't still be interested in creating a tag for it... (How ignorant this sounds... :/ )